# Como hacer el "print" en pantalla , SI es número primo o NO?

Tags: python

Estoy iniciando en python, necesito que print una mensage diciendo si es o no numero primo. como esta mi muestra si es True o False.

```py
def es_primo(numero): 
    
    if n == 2: # Comproba si n es 2 (unico primo par).
        
        return True
        
    if n < 2 or not n % 2: # Comproba si es menor de 2 o es par.
        
        return False
        
    return not any(n % i == 0 for i in range(3, int(n**0.5) + 1, 2)) # Comproba divisibilidad en entero impar entre 3 y sqrt(n).

n = int(numero)     
print(es_primo(numero))
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cuál es el problema con el código que nos compartes? Podrías por favor, editar la pregunta y explicar con un poco más de detalle qué problema tienes?

Comment: Pues cambia la forma en que lo llamas a `if es_primo(numero): print("Es primo") else: print("No es primo")`

Comment: Con otra función ? pues lo intente y no funciono , sabes, hay otra manera ? Sigo intentando ...

Comment: @RicardoMCosta Si lo has intentado y no ha funcionado, edita la pregunta (enlace "Editar" debajo) para mostrar qué has intentado y de qué forma ha fallado, para que podamos indicarte qué estaba mal. De lo contrario no sé cómo podríamos saberlo...

Comment: si solo tienes el problema de imprimir puedes utilizar algo así?? `respuesta = f'El número {numero} ' + ('ES primo' if es_primo(numero) else 'NO ES primo')`

Comment: @tomygijon Por que comentas en lugar de proponer tus ideas explicadas en la zona de respuestas?

Comment: @DanteS. me parecía un código excesivamente simple para hacer esa respuesta. No sé si lo conseguí pero ya está preparada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la manera más simple que puedes hacerlo es usando un selector if, que evalúa la condición de tu función (Verdadera o Falsa) y de acuerdo a esa respuesta darle información al usuario de este modo:

## Condicional if (si... sino)

```
if <condicion>:
    # Esto solo sucede si se cumple la condición
    # es decir, si lo que resulta de evaluar
    # condicion = True
else:
    # Estas líneas indentadas solo ocurren 
    # en caso que no se cumpla lo anterior
```

## Ejemplo

Veamos una aplicación para ver si un número es positivo o negativo

```
def esPositivoNegativo(number):
    if number >= 0:
        print("Es positivo")
    else:
       print("Es negativo")

numero = 128
esPositivoNegativo(numero) # Muestra "Es positivo"
numero = -9
esPositivoNegativo(numero) # Muestra "Es negativo"
numero = 0
esPositivoNegativo(numero) # Muestra "Es positivo" ¡¡GRAN DEBATE!!
```

## Aplicación

Usando este principio, tu código quedaría del siguiente modo:

```
def es_primo(numero): 
    
    if n == 2: # Comproba si n es 2 (unico primo par).
        
        return True
        
    if n < 2 or not n % 2: # Comproba si es menor de 2 o es par.
        
        return False
        
    return not any(n % i == 0 for i in range(3, int(n**0.5) + 1, 2)) # Comproba divisibilidad en entero impar entre 3 y sqrt(n).

numero = input("Ingrese un numero: ")
n = int(numero)
if es_primo(numero):
    print("Es primo")
else:
    print("No es primo")
```

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser así ? @Marcelo Zarate

```
def es_primo(num): # Comprueba si es número primo.
    
    contador = 0
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            contador += 1
            
    if contador == 2:
        return "Sí es número primo" # Argumento para True.
    else:
        return "No es número primo" # Argumento para False.

num = int(numero)
print(es_primo(num))
```

Comment: Está muy bien, la función como la escribiste ahora, lo resuelve más intuitivamente. ¿Pero de dónde sale la variable `numero`?

Comment: @Marcelo Zarate, sale de otra función arriba. Estoy empezando en python pero practicando muchísimo, gracias a ti en poco tiempo veo muchísimo más claro.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

En muchos lengueges existe una cosa llamada **operador ternario**.
En python sigue la forma

```
condition_if_true if condition else condition_if_false
```

En tu caso se puede resolver así:

```py
respuesta = f'El número {numero} ' + ('ES primo' if es_primo(numero) else 'NO ES primo')
```

En respuesta a tu función es `'Es primo' SI es_primo(numero) SINO 'NO ES primo`.

Simplificas el código y queda más *pythonico* .

Answer (score -1):

Esta funcion retorna True si es primo y False si no es primo.

```
def isPrime(self, x):
    if x <= 1 or (x>2 and x%2==0) or (x>3 and x%3==0) or (x>5 and x%5==0):
        return False
    elif x == 2 or x == 3:
        return True
    else:
        cont = 0
        for i in range(3, x+1):
            if x%i == 0:
                cont = cont + 1
                if cont > 1:
                    return False

        if cont == 1:
            return True
```

Comment: El usuario no quiere eso. Esto ya lo tiene